# (Visual Studio Code) How to get the "<?php ?>" structure by only writing "php" and hitting enter like Atom

Tags: php, autofill

Im noob with MS Visual Studio Code. Im migratting from Atom and i couldnt find any extension that solve my problem.

In atom i just write "php" and hit enter and the php Opening and closing tags just appear.

Any idea how to do that on  Visual Studio code?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer I linked to is a couple of years old so I installed visual studio code to verify that it still works. Seems to do the trick. (Important to note that it's an html snippet.)